# jQuery Nested Sortable - Can't move nested pre-populated LI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, nested-sortable

I am using nestedSortable 1.3.5 from Manuele J Sarfatti: https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable

Using this I face the problem that pre-populated sub-elements cannot be moved/dragged. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gcWQQ/3/

Any ideas, how to solve that problem?

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use these options:

```
listType         : 'ol',
items            : 'li',
handle           : '.project-sortHandle',
toleranceElement : 'div'
```

example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gcWQQ/4/